# system administrator ans user wheel in mac os x

Tags: mac, permissions

I have a folder created by a System administrator that I can't delete, there is also a user wheel user. actually I'm the system administrator but i can't delete the file, I can look into it and open the file but nothing else, the folder contains an old antivirus for mac by bitdefender. 
can some one help me in discovering what is this user and how I can cancel the file 
thank

Comment: "wheel" is a group of super-users that is created ad-hoc by Unix and its derivatives to allow temporary super-user privileges to applications when they install. It's probably what happened when you installed, then uninstalled BitDefender. The only exhaustive way to uninstall an application on a Mac is to use a third-party (e.g. AppRemover, which is very good at that), or to use a series of Terminal commands that not everyone wants, or knows how, to use. What you can do is boot in Safe Mode, and try a chmod command in Terminal about this file, but I'm surprised you can't do it in your session.

Comment: The only sensible way to uninstall an antivirus from Mac is to use the Uninstaller app, usually on the original install .dmg, sometimes copied at install to the Utilities folder. Antiviruses really resist manual uninstall… of course. You may have to boot to Recovery, see https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/1784/ or https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/1446/ depending on how much of a mess you've made already ;)

Comment: I've already tried with bitdefender installer, was the first thing I did, but once started the deleting process, the uninstaller ask for an administrator as I'm the administrator I enter my p/w, but is not enough, as the the only administrator able to read and write is system. I can't even add another administrator to the folder as only system can. of course I tried some also third party installer but I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The simple 'Golden Rule' for Mac installs is …
"If it went in with an installer, it must come out with an uninstaller."

So, if you just copied it over from a .dmg into Applications, then you can just drag it to the Trash to uninstall it. Any extraneous data removal, using any of the plethora of uninstaller apps is actually optional; you will regain some disk space, but functionally there's no difference.

If, on the other hand, you had to run a .pgk app requiring admin perms to install, then you really need to be looking for the uninstaller if you ever need to remove it. The reason they need admin perms at install is because they need to access system-level areas.
In these days of SIP & read-only system partitions, this is even more important.

Things like antiviruses are especially resistant to being hauled to the Trash - that's their job, to prevent bad actors disabling them - or even local admins, if it's an Endpoint Security version rather than just consumer.

An uninstaller for this type of app is almost the only way to remove them. Your alternative is to reboot to Recovery [possibly also requiring disabling of SIP] & picking the bits out by hand… once you've found where they all live.

For BitDefender see the standard uninstall instructions at Bitdefender support - [How to uninstall Bitdefender Antivirus for Mac](https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/1784/) or if that isn't fully successful or you want to try this by hand, the manual version at [How to remove Bitdefender Antivirus for Mac when uninstall doesn’t work](https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/1446/) (though the second is only apparently tested to Sierra; idk how much more difficult it would be in Catalina, with a read-only OS partition - I cannot test, I only have Mojave here)

If you really struggle at following the instructions, then re-download the installer.
Install it again, then uninstall correctly, using the uninstaller app.

Comment: thank for you reply, it's really a mess there the problem is not for the space  but that bit defender start running every this i start the iMac..). the bitdefender uninstaller doesn't work it requires to delete the p/w of the 'system' administrator, even if I'm the administrator i can't.  of course if I drag and drop into the bin it's the same it ask for an administrator I enter my p/w and nothing... only system admin can . and i can't modify the permission of the folder containing the only system can.

Comment: That sounds like you are trying to uninstall an Endpoint Security version - ie a corporate version. This is designed to much more stringently prevent local users from removing it. You will need to refer up to your IT department if that is the case.

Comment: I'm a private, not a company unfortunately (...), I think I need a professional intervention but we are stuck with this virus thing these day

Comment: You'll have to try following the 'how to uninstall if you messed it up' page linked above.

Comment: I also  tried with scrutil disable in terminal in recovery mode to access the sip but not  going through terminal and hand picking the files to delete but using a third party unistaller, but same result it always requires the system user p/w.

Comment: BitDefender give you the full instruction-set. Why are you still messing around with a 3rd party uninstaller?

Comment: yes u r right third party unistaller are useless .. the problem I guess is there are some kernel protected files, but even if Bitdefender guide is clear enough i'm not a so advanced user, to go into terminal and working there.... and i'm not sure that is a kernel is the problem because all the bitdefender folder is not deletable

Comment: I disagree about third-parties like AppRemover being useless. They exist for a reason, and that reason is that macOS / OS X only allows users to remove the tip of the iceberg when they uninstall an app. Even the uninstaller that comes with the .dmg file doesn't remove .plist files all over your system disk, sometimes (often times), in the hope that you'll want to install their app again. Some, like VirtualBox, will even leave kexts in your Startup Items folder, that the OS has to load on startup when the app itself has been removed *for years*, so no, third-party app removers aren't useless...

Comment: The advice I gave you the other day still stands, @nick501: boot in Recovery Mode, open Terminal, type "chmod 777", drag-drop the file onto the Terminal window, press Enter, enter your admin password, then navigate to the file location, try to delete it with the Option/Alt + Command + Delete key combo and see what happens.

Comment: I meant useless in that case, ad the two  I  tried weren't able to delete the bit defender files, the  only result  get is it stopped to be launched  each time I start the computer